# Find all possible paths of a specified length between two nodes on a graph

Tags: r, igraph

For medium-sized (~50 nodes, avg. degree: ~4), undirected, unweighted graphs I want to enumerate all possible paths of a specified length between two nodes i and j using R.

The package igraph provides `all_simple_paths`, which I could use and then simply subset the result to paths of the length I desire. Yet, the problem is that `all_simple_paths` by default also enumerates all possible longer paths, which takes hours, even for rather small networks.

I know there are several very similar questions around on SO, yet non specific for `R`, and more importantly non more recent than `igraph`'s `all_simple_paths`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you do not want all possible paths between `i` and `j`, but rather just the shortest ones -- is that right?

You can achieve this with the `all_shortest_paths` function from igraph.

Given:

```
require(igraph)
edges= graph.formula(A - B,
                     A - C,
                     B - C,
                     B - C,
                     C - D,
                     B - D,
                     D - E)
```

if i=A and j=D (just saying):

```
>all_shortest_paths(edges,from="A", to="D")
$res
$res[[1]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A C D

$res[[2]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B D


$nrgeo
[1] 1 1 1 2 0
```

On the contrary, `all_simple_paths` would give you longer paths (l=4), which I you do not want:

```
> all_simple_paths(edges,from="A", to="D")
[[1]]
+ 4/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B C D

[[2]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B D

[[3]]
+ 4/5 vertices, named:
[1] A C B D

[[4]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A C D
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but no, I don't want "all shortest paths" but I do want "all possible paths of a specified length"

Comment: Woops. I misunderstood that. Maybe you can try to subset the shortest paths set instead of the simplest one, but that will only do the trick for *some* possible lengths. Let me know if you find something!